# Mongoose schema method checking password against passed input

Tags: mongoose

Im having trouble understanding how to use the compare password on the mongoose schema `Person`. I have a login path that retrieves one record based on an email match.

```js
var Person = require('../models/person.js');

exports.login = function (req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    Person.findOne({ email }, function (err, user) {
        if(err){
            res.status(501).send(error);
        }
        if(!user){
            res.status(401);
        }
        if(user){
            console.log(typeof user)
           // const test = new Person(user);
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {
  
            });

        }
    })
}
```

```js
personSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password, done) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    done(err, isMatch);
  });
};
```

I am trying to call the comparePassword method but this.password is null below is the schema for Person.

```js
var personSchema = new Schema({
  first       :   {type: String, required: 'FirstNameInvalid'},
  last        :   String,
  email       :   {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, required: 'EmailInvalid'},
  password    :   {type: String, select: false, required: 'PasswordInvalid'}
});
```

Comment: Where are you trying to log`this.password` ?

Comment: not log but it is undefined in the comparePassword method i think it is the select: false that causes it not to come back but if i make a request for people later the passwords would come back if i removed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `select: false` only when you hit the login route with `select()`

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    Person.findOne({ email })
        .select('password')
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if(err){
                res.status(501).send(error);
            }
            if(!user){
                res.status(401);
            }
            if(user){
                console.log(typeof user)
                user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {

                });

            }
    });
}
```